# How can i add ads in flutter, without admob?

Tags: flutter, admob, ads, google-mobile-ads

Hi everyone i have a problem with my admob account. Since 2-3 months i can’t log in and i think it never works for me. I need a mobile ads. Is there anyone using mobile ads other than admob?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Huawei Ads Kit Flutter plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/huawei_ads

Comment: Huawei not working in Turkiye :) but thank for answer bro!